# Showing $A+uv^T$ is nonsingular and finding $A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose $A$ is a nonsingular matrix of order $n$, $u$ and $v$ are $n$-vectors, and $v^T A^{−1}u\neq −1$. Show that $A + uv^T$ is nonsingular with inverse

$$(A+uv^T)^{−1} =A^{−1} − \frac{1}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}$$

Comment: Did you try to solve the problem yourself ? If yes, What did you do ?

Comment: same question here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937653/why-does-this-least-squares-approach-to-proving-the-sherman-morrison-formula-wor/1938944?noredirect=1#comment3980454_1938944

Answer (score 6):

**Show that it's non-singular**

*Hint*: $M$ is non-singular if $Mx = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=0$. So if $A+uv^T$ is singular there is a $x\neq 0$ such that $Ax+uv^T x=0$, show that there is no such $x$.

**Show that the inverse is given by what you quoted**

*Hint*: just test it, if you multiply the formula by $(A+uv^T)$ and massage it a bit you will get the identity matrix (you will need to use the symmetry of the inner product (i.e., $x^T y =y^Tx$) and that's pretty much it)

Also this is a well known formula called the [*Sherman-Morrison formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), which you may want to look up.

Comment: The first step is redundant if you can show that the given matrix “products” with another one the identity.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is invertible, then

$$\begin{array}{rl} (\mathrm A + \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top})^{-1} &= (\mathrm A (\mathrm I_n + \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top}))^{-1}\\ &= (\mathrm I_n + \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top})^{-1} \mathrm A^{-1}\\ &= (\mathrm I_n - \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top} + (\mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top})^2 - (\mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top})^3 + \cdots) \, \mathrm A^{-1}\\ &= \mathrm A^{-1} - \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} + \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} - \cdots\\ &= \mathrm A^{-1} - \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \left( 1 - \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u + (\mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u)^2 - \cdots \right) \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1}\end{array}$$

where the geometric series

$$1 - \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u + (\mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u)^2 - \cdots = \dfrac{1}{1 + \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u}$$

converges if $| \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u | < 1$. Assuming convergence,

$$\boxed{(\mathrm A + \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top})^{-1} = \mathrm A^{-1} - \dfrac{\mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1}}{1 + \mathrm v^{\top} \mathrm A^{-1} \mathrm u}}$$

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, this is known as the *Sherman-Morrison formula*. One can actually **deduce** the formula using only knowledge about matrix multiplication, without guessing or knowing the form of the inverse in advance. Suppose first that the inverse exists. Let $(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}+B$. Expanding $(A+uv^T)(A^{-1}+B) = I$, we get $I+uv^TA^{-1}+(A+uv^T)B=I$ and hence
$$
B = -(A+uv^T)^{-1}uv^TA^{-1} = -(A^{-1}+B)uv^TA^{-1}.\tag{1}
$$
Let $w=-(A^{-1}+B)u$, so $(1)$ gives $B = wv^TA^{-1}$ and
\begin{align}
B&= -(A^{-1}+wv^TA^{-1})uv^TA^{-1}\\
&= -A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1} - w\color{red}{(v^TA^{-1}u)}v^TA^{-1}\\
&= -A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1} - \color{red}{(v^TA^{-1}u)}wv^TA^{-1}\\
&= -A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1} - (v^TA^{-1}u)B.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
B = -\frac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}
$$
and the inversion formula follows from $(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}+B$. You can easily verify by direct calculation that $(A+uv^T)(A^{-1}+B)$ is indeed equal to $I$.