# Why does this least-squares approach to proving the Sherman–Morrison Formula work?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, inverse

Suppose $A$ is an invertible square matrix and $u,v$ are column vectors. Suppose furthermore that $1 + v^T A^{-1}u \neq 0$. Then the Sherman–Morrison formula states that:

$$
(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^T A^{-1} \over 1 + v^T A^{-1}u}
$$

Here, $uv^T$ is the outer product of two vectors $u$ and $v$.

A proof I saw online was here: [Direct Derivation of the
Sherman-Morrison Formula](http://cis.poly.edu/~mleung/CS3734/s05/ch02/ShermanMorrison4-out.pdf).

To outline the proof:

They find the inverse by solving the linear problem:

$$
(A-uv^T)x=b
$$

They pre-multiply the equation by $A^{-1}$ and let $z = A^{-1}$ and $y=A^{-1}b$. Then,

$$
x-zv^Tx = y
$$

They then let $\alpha = v^Tx$, so that they get:

$$
\alpha - v^Tz\alpha = v^Ty.
$$

They then solve for $\alpha$:

$\alpha = \dfrac{v^Ty}{1-v^Tz}$

They then claim the solution can be written as $x=y+\alpha z$.

$$
x=y+\alpha z = A^{-1}b+A^{-1}u(1-v^TA^{-1}u)^{-1}v^TA^{-1}b
$$

Then, they say that

$$
x = [A^{-1}+A^{-1}u(1-v^TA^{-1}u)^{-1}v^TA^{-1}]b
$$

and that the inverse is $A^{-1}+A^{-1}u(1-v^TA^{-1}u)^{-1}v^TA^{-1}$

**What I don't understand** is how this even works. I do get the gist, in that they claim that if $y=Ax$, then if you use least squares and solve for $x = A^{-1}y$, then whatever is in the A^{-1} should be the inverse.

However, what confuses me is why we solve for $\alpha$ (is this like finding the $\beta$ in a least squares format?) optimized? What is so special about it? Also, why is pre-multiplying the equation by $A^{-1}$ the same as taking derivatives, etc? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little easier to use an inner product, $\langle a,b\rangle=a^{T}b=b^{T}a$. This helps separate vectors and scalars. You want to solve for $x$ in this equation, given $b$:
$$
            (A+uv^{T})x=b \\
            Ax+\langle v,x\rangle u = b \\
            x +\langle v,x\rangle A^{-1}u=A^{-1}b
$$
This gives you a scalar and a vector involving $x$. To turn this into a scalar equation, take the inner product on the left with $v$:
$$
               \langle v,x\rangle + \langle v,x\rangle\langle v,A^{-1}u\rangle=\langle v,A^{-1}b\rangle
$$
Now you can solve for $\langle v,x\rangle$.
$$
                \langle v,x\rangle = \frac{\langle v,A^{-1}b\rangle}{1+\langle v,A^{-1}u\rangle}.
$$
Finally, substitute back into the third equation of this post.
\begin{align}
     (A+uv^T)^{-1}b= x & =A^{-1}b-\langle v,x\rangle A^{-1}u \\
        & =A^{-1}b-\frac{\langle v,A^{-1}b\rangle}{1+\langle v,A^{-1}u\rangle}A^{-1}u \\
   & = A^{-1}b-\frac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}b}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}
\end{align}

Comment: do you have an obvious argument why $(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} + wz^T$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 : Where are you getting your expression?

Comment: @user1952009 Compare the final expression I have with the first equation of the question.

Comment: Well I'm dumb : $rank((A+uv^T)^{-1} - A^{-1}) = 1$ is equivalent to $rank(I- (A+uv^T)A^{-1}) = rank(I- I- uv^T A^{-1}) = rank(-uv^TA^{-1}) = 1$

Comment: @user1952009 : <b>General Note:</b> In general if $B$ is a rank one operator, and $A$ is invertible, then
\begin{align}
    (A+B)^{-1}&=(A(I+A^{-1}B))^{-1} \\
              &=(I+A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1} \\
              &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(A^{-1}B)^{n}A^{-1} \\
              &=A^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(A^{-1}B)^{n}A^{-1} \\
              &=A^{-1}+CA^{-1},
\end{align}
where $C$ is a rank one operator.

Comment: Yes that was what I tried, but ... ok I'm dumb again : $(uv^T)^n = u (v^Tu)^{n-1}v^T = \alpha\ uv^T$ where $\alpha =  (v^Tu)^{n-1}$. So in general $f(uv^T) = f(0) + \frac{f(v^T u)-f(0)}{v^Tu} uv^T$ whenever $f$ is analytic

Comment: @TrialAndError Could you tell me why you decided to solve for $<v,x>$? What makes it so special that we would want to find this point (I am assuming we are finding this max/min-imized)? Thanks

Comment: @user321627 : Because you have an equation for $x$ that involves $x$ and $\langle v,x\rangle$, which means you have an equation involve a vector and a scalar, both of which depend on $x$. However, by taking the inner product with $v$, you end up with an equation involving $x$ only through the scalar $\langle v,x\rangle$. Then you can solve for $\langle v,x\rangle$ in terms of other quantities. Then you can solve for $x$ using that.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thanks, so when I am looking for $<v,x>$, is this the same as finding $\hat{\beta}$ when I am solving the equation $Y=X\beta$? Is there a minimization thing going on above? In other words, can I also do it but with a derivative and with a minimization scheme? thanks!!

Comment: @user321627 : I believe this is the same as the scalar $\alpha$ in the post. But there may be an error in the post because he gets a negative in the denominator instead of a positive. So it's not really a least squares type of argument. It's just a systematic way of dealing with the one-dimensional perturbation and scalar associated with that perturbation.